# hook LayoutInflater and change values when inflating views

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I want to implement a custom LayoutInflater that scales dimension values, for example,
use:

```
int scale = 2;
MyInflater.inflate(R.id.testview, null, parent, scale);
```

will inflate a xml with all dimension values doubled.

that is, a xml like this:

```
<View android:layout_width="10dp" android:layout_height="10dp" />
```

will inflate to a view that width and height are 20dp.

`LayoutInflater.Factory` cannot solve my problem.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Comment: "LayoutInflater.Factory cannot solve my problem." -- why not?

Comment: @CommonsWare if use `LayoutInflater.Factory`, I have to create every view myself, because there is no chaining super call; And LayoutParams generation is out of `createViewFromTag()`, where Factory's `onCreateView()` is called, so in Factory's `onCreateView()`, modifying LayoutParams is impossible.

Comment: I dont quite understand the question, you want to scale the View from the xml when inflating?

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski yepp, I want to scale all size in dp when inflating the view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could use this code to loop all the children of your inflated layout and multiply the width and height by setting the LayoutParams:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    MyInflater inflater = new MyInflater(LayoutInflater.from(this), this);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_view, viewGroup, true, 2);
}

private class MyInflater extends LayoutInflater {

    private int mScale;

    protected MyInflater(LayoutInflater original, Context newContext) {
        super(original, newContext);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutInflater cloneInContext(Context newContext) {
        return null;
    }

    public View inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, int scale) {
        mScale = scale;
        // This will return the parent of the inflated resource (if it has one)
        View viewRoot = super.inflate(resource, root, attachToRoot);

        if (viewRoot instanceof ViewGroup) {
            loopViewGroup((ViewGroup) viewRoot, viewRoot == root);
        } else {
            doubleDimensions(viewRoot);
        }
        return viewRoot;
    }

    private void doubleDimensions(View view) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        Log.d(TAG, "Before => "+params.width+" : "+params.height);
        params.width = params.width * mScale;
        params.height = params.height * mScale;
        Log.d(TAG, "After => "+params.width+" : "+params.height);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private void loopViewGroup(ViewGroup group, boolean isRoot) {
        // If viewRoot == root, skip setting ViewGroup params
        if (!isRoot) doubleDimensions(group);

        // Loop the ViewGroup children
        for (int i=0; i<group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = group.getChildAt(i);
            // If a child is another ViewGroup, loop it too
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                loopViewGroup((ViewGroup) child, false);
            } else {
                doubleDimensions(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this would solve the problem, but may have performance issues? and I want *ALL* dimensions scaled, so I'm thinking of modifying xml attrs when inflating .

Comment: and this approach can be a backup plan. upvoted, thanks!